# Quick html markup issue

Tags: css, html

I am trying to do a quick markup for my page.

I want to have my title shown next line of my `<nav>` tag instead of right next to it. How do I do it?

HTML :

```html
<nav>
    <ui> 
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ui>
</nav>

<section id='title'>
    <div>title 1</div>
    <div>texts here....</div>
</section>
```

CSS :

```css
nav {   
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ui li{
    list-style: none;
    font:bold .6em arial;
    float: left;
    margin: .3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
}
```

The *title* and *texts here...* are right next to my menu but I want them under the menu. How do I do this?

Comment: it's `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net when asking questions like this...

Anyhow, there are several alternatives.

For example: Give the nav or the #title section, a `clear: both` attribute:

```
#title {
    clear: both;
}
```

For the academics of it, like other people said on this page, if there are other floating elements to the right of the #title section, the following code would fit better:

```
#title {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: +1 for many reasons, I was about to say the same.... here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k6SUE/5/

Comment: but it wouldn't be helpful if we want another object to be floating to the right of title. See the @Optimus Prime  below comment.

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya : Fixed. Thank you and Optimus Prime

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya sure but add more specific points to the question then. This answer is still good, what if a title shouldn't have something floating right? we don't know so we don't care :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please change your `ui` tag to `ul`.

An unordered list in HTML should be like `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

Just added to css,

```
section{
    clear : left;
}
```

OR if you have multiple sections,

```
#title{
    clear : left;
}
```

`clear:both` should not be used, if you have another floating object to right of title.
Then changing width to 100% would also not be good for you.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zcM4/1)**

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya In this case of course, but it wouldn't be helpful if we want another object to be floating to the right of title.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add:

```
width:100%;
float:left;
```

to the nav's css.

The section tag has no reason to drop below the nav as the nav's width will default to some smaller width (that doesn't take up the whole width of the containing div). This allows the section tag to easily float left along side the nav tag's content.

Answer (score 0):

Use clear b/w both  and

```
<nav>
   <ul> 
      <li>item1</li>
       <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>



 <section id='title'>
      <div>title 1</div>
       <div>texts here....</div>
  </section>
```

add to css `#title {clear:both;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/2Fgdw/

Comment: You don't need an extra `div` for this objective.

Answer (score 0):

As Optimus Prime noted, it what the `ui` in your css should be `ul` - Both `<nav>` and `<section>` are block level elements and will naturally be 100% width and force the next to drop to the next line.

Comment: I'm not going to post the code, but if you would like to see how I would have gone about this - I made a fiddle with everything commented. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/KuHhf/  Good luck!